# Workflow or Flow for Auto Populate

Tags: workflow, formula-field, visual-workflow, field-update

Can a selective email address filtered as criteria set upon email to case submission, to update Picklist automatically determining which picklist A,B,C to reflect email address CAR@EMAIL for A, BUS@EMAIL FOR B and Truck@email for C. What best method CAN be used WF or Formula or Flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Process Builder Flow is the easiest; it allows you to do all three in a single element. Workflow would require 3 separate rules, which is not necessarily a deal breaker, but less efficient overall. Formulas do not directly "update" fields. They're calculated on the fly when you query the database.

If you're just interested in having the value available to display, you can forego the picklist and use a formula instead. However, keep in mind that formulas require a full table scan when using them as filters, so they are less efficient than picklists in that regard.

Comment: Unfortunately, I had attempted using the Process Builder to run the 3 task for Single element. The trigger don't seems to be initiating the update for Update Records. This is the process used, Object Case (when a record is created or edited). Criteria Name - Business and Conditions are Met, Set Conditions Case.SuppliedEmail Contains String @abcorp.com, Conditions (All Conditions Met). Update Records (ABCORP), Record (Case), No criteria  just update records. Set New Field Values - Field Business Type Multipicklist Value ABCORP. Nothing updated, please shed some light